# Git: Files in vendor are not found

Tags: php, git, symfony

I use `Symfony2` in my project and switched to my branch `EXAMPLE-123` in which some days ago. I integrated pagination with `KnpPaginator`. When I just tried to deploy, I received the following message:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBoundle' not found in AppKernel.php on line 16
```

Line 16 of `AppKernel.php` says:

```
new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
```

I have no clue why the bundle is not recognized, because in my PHP editor I can see all the bundle files in my vendor folder (`vendor/knplabs/...`).

Another warning message that might be helpful for solving this problem: When in GIT I am in another branch and checkout to the `EXAMPLE-123` branch, I get the message:

> ```
> warning: unable to rmdir vendor/knplabs/knp-components: Directory not empty
> warning: unable to rmdir vendo
> ```
>
> Blockquote

r/knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle/Knp/Bundle/PaginatorBundle:

> Directory not empty

Who can make sense of this problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: Is the vendor folder git-tracked? Because it looks like `vendor/knplabs/knp-components` is different from a branch to another.

Comment: Where do you get the error? after deploying on the production server?

Comment: I get the error after deploying on the dev server

Comment: the files were not tracked. i solved the problem. thank you

Comment: @Max, *how* did you solve the problem? In general, `vendor/` *shouldn't* be tracked. Please share your solution by answering your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files under `vendor/` aren't supposed to be tracked, i.e. it's supposed to be in your `.gitignore` file. Instead, the `composer` utility should be used to download the packages and install them.

In your case I would suggest to:

1. Unpack the project into a temporary directory,
2. Run `composer install`
3. Deploy the temporary directory contents.